# AppDynamics Alerting - How to trigger alert based on number of call (trxn) per hour health rule. (example call < 10/hour)

Tags: appdynamics

My requirement is - AppD Health rule should trigger alert when call per hour < x (eg: 10). But while setting this,  I could not find call/hour metric in AppD controller. It has all perMin metrics. So how to achieve this alerting criteria in AppD health rule?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try setting "Use data from last" to **60 minutes**. In Criteria-tab use "Single Metric" with **Sum** of "Calls per Minute" and define your threshold.

Answer (score 0):

As per your scenario, you can go for "Use data from last" 60 minutes and evaluation time will be based on your choice.
Instead of sum, you can go for static values like numbers if you have a previous metric trend of your application.